# Особенности класса WebProxy: в чем может быть проблема?

Tags: c#

Сочиняю парсер в качестве учебной задачи, и все нормально работает, пока не добавляю объект WebProxy, вот 2 строки кода:

```
WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("168.213.3.106", 80);
request.Proxy = wp;
```

программа намертво встает (не зависает, а как бы перестает выполняться). Что делать?!

Весь метод:

```
    public static string DownloadHtml(string uri, Encoding encoding)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;

    WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("168.213.3.106", 80);
    request.Proxy = wp;

    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)";
    request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    request.KeepAlive = true;

    // получаем ответ
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    // поток данных получаемых с сервера
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding);
    sr.ReadLine();
    string html = sr.ReadToEnd();

    return html;
}
```

Comment: В каком месте программа "перестает выполняться"? Именно в показанной вами строчке - или все-таки на строчке `request.GetResponse()`?

Comment: Хост 168.213.3.106 пингуется? Там точно на 80м порту висит прокси-сервер?

Comment: Может нужно просто запустить все это в потоке? И по ходу выполнения потока выводить состояние его выполнения.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется действительно дело было не в коде, а в хосте. 
Вот пара ссылок для проверки:
http://goldhous.com/programmirovanie/2012/01/17/ping-hosta-na-s.html
http://s0m0m.ru/?p=566